# Google Docs Spreadsheet sections

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using Google Spreadsheets. I want to be able to have several different sections all on one spreadsheet:

- an income section with totals there
- an expense section with totals in it
- etc.

How do I create these different sections so that I can have just pure white space around each section? And to be able to add new rows to one section without it affecting the other?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any way to fulfil your need for "pure white" padding that automatically surrounds a section of a sheet. But I would recommend simply using separate sheets in the same document, and merging them if and when necessary for aesthetic purposes.